# My Apache 2 server is giving an error and 403 error, help?

Tags: server, apache2

My Apache 2 web server is giving an error

[image]

and the file is with these permissions

```
drwsrwsrwt 1 root root   512 Feb 24 10:41 web
```

I try to use chmod but still no response, I use Linux subsystem and I put my files directly to the folder but is giving and 403 error response how can I resolve this?

Comment: Can you indicate what version of Ubuntu you are using?  Also, what is the *full* path whose permissions you are checking?  I don't know what `web` is, but it should be `/var/www/html/`, I think...

Comment: I use Linux subsystem and don't ubuntu, the directory is /var/www/html but I create another file in /var/www/html that calls web so yes is the directory /var/www/html but I create the web file so the directory is now /var/www/html/web. Sorry about that...

Comment: The image you posted is for the address 127.0.0.1 .  This means it is having problems accessing the top of your web site -- that is `/var/www/html/`.  It hasn't yet got to anything inside that directory.  So, you should check that the permissions are correct from `/` all the way down to `/var/www/html/`.  Also, take a look at the web server logs.  I don't know what you mean by "Linux subsystem", to be honest, so I can't help you further than this.The logs are probably in `/var/log/`, but it will vary depending on the Linux variant...

Comment: thanks, I will check, just a little thing Linux subsystem is the Linux terminal to windows is an entire operating system but you don't need to have another operating system

Comment: Oh!  I see.  I saw that on a colleague's computer once.  If I'm not mistaken, I think that subsystem is Ubuntu, is it not?  I only took a glance at her Windows and am not really sure.  Anyway, which variant of Linux matters sometimes because the paths and default settings might change slightly.